# Problem of installing ubuntu 14.o4 in windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Oracle VM virtual Box and while creating virtual machine, it was showing only ubuntu 32 bit.It was not showing 64 bit,please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a proper answer but i could not comment that's why i am answering. First of all, i think your question is wrong. It should be like

> no option to create 64-bit guests in virtualbox

.
This type of question had already been asked. You can check this link [enable option to create 64-bit guests in virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429768/vm-virtualbox-doesnt-allow-to-enable-64-bit-guest-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-lenovo-g5)